# datastax cluster try to connect a dead node

Tags: cassandra, datastax

When I started the cluster, I can see in the log it always try to connect to a dead node which I cannot even find.
The strange thing is when I runned **nodetool ring**  or **nodetool status**  , I cannot find this dead host anymore. That means I cannot remove it by executing **nodetool removenode** .
I guess somebody else had added this node to cluster, but I don`t know how did it get removed.
How should I resolve it ?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Have solved this problem by following :http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_gossip_purge.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nodetool removenode` has proven problematic in the past, and there are a few ways to get around this.

Which version are you on?  If you are running the new 2.2 version, you can use `nodetool assassinate`:

```
$ nodetool -u cassandra -pw cassandra assassinate 10.0.0.100
```

Basically, this is enough of a problem that it was promoted to a nodetool command with version 2.2 thanks to [CASSANDRA-7935](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7935).  If you are running on a version prior to 2.2, you can force the removal of a node via the JMX Term tool ([as documented here](https://gist.github.com/justenwalker/8338334)):

```
$>open localhost:7199
#Connection to localhost:7199 is opened
$>bean org.apache.cassandra.net:type=Gossiper
#bean is set to org.apache.cassandra.net:type=Gossiper
$>run unsafeAssassinateEndpoint 10.0.0.100
#calling operation unsafeAssassinateEndpoint of mbean org.apache.cassandra.net:type=Gossiper
#operation returns:
null
$>quit
#bye
```

Comment: Hi Aaron ,thanks for your help! I had solved this by following:http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_gossip_purge.html          I didn`t test your way, but I think it works either. By the way the version is 2.0.1